# Activity (.java) error

Tags: java, android

Everything was fine with my app. All errors as in picture 1 have suddenly appeared in all Java activities that comprise my app. I don't know what happens to cause all of these errors.
[image: First Error]

When I click Alt+Enter to get help or solution suggestions, I come out with the dialog as in second picture.
[image: After pressing Alt+Enter]

Hopefully I can get your appreciated help to solve this issue,
thank you in advance.

Comment: have you invalidate cache and restart AS?

Comment: no I didn't…  you advising me to do or asking if I have did

Comment: @Me.Moh consider ZeroOne question rhetoric. If you have done it , that is fine. If you have not- do it. If invalidate cache and restart do not work, make sure your gradle is correct. And yes, post your build.gradle .

Comment: thank you for help, as zeroone have said, invalidate cache/restart is the solution thank you again